# Reading events from eventhub EventProcessorHost Vs EventHubReceiver

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, event-processor-host

I tries reading events from eventhub through a console applications 1 with EventHubReceiver and another application with EventProcessorHost, what I notices is EventProcessorHost reads faster than EventHubReceiver.. Is that true?

Answer (score 3):

**No! EventProcessorHost cannot be faster than EventHubReceiver**, because EventProcessorHost uses EventHubReceiver underneath :)

EventProcessorHost (hereby, I will use `EPH`) is a simplified version of receiving from Microsoft Azure 
EventHubs and it is built on top of `EventHubReceiver`. EPH receives from EventHub and automatically distributes partitions across multiple instances of EPH using the same storage account.

EPH is a very good starting point to explore EventHubs. To use `EventHubReceiver` - one needs more advanced understanding of `EventHubs` in general.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to use/configure both, it's not possible to say without your code. The speed will depend on batch size, prefetch, concurrency etc.

`Host` uses `Receiver` behind the scenes. So, your choice should be about the API they provide, not the speed.

It makes sense to stick to `EventProcessorHost` unless you need low-level API, which you most probably won't.